# Highlight subsection of editText

Tags: android

I am creating an application where the user has 4 arrows, up, down, left and right. When a user pressed the left arrow it then displays

```
0
```

left again then adds a units/hundred/thousands... columns to the current number.

Up will add 1 to the current column number and down accordingly and right/left to transverse through the number.
let's say you have a number : 2400

and you want to edit the tens column, I would want the 0 to be highlighted to show the user what number they are editing.

Comment: What's your actual question?  If its how to select text, use setSelection

Comment: @GabeSechan yes and no, its to set a certain section of the edit text highlighted, not the entire thing.

Comment: setSelection takes a start and end index.